# How to display how many visitors visit my web sorted by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database, where are records of users with date (when they visited my website):

Picture of database with visitor's IP and time of visit
[image]

And I wanted to display by SQL query only date and how many times was my website visited at this date. Like this:

This is what I wanted to

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: you can use `COUNT()`. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx - *appropriately enough*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate by `datum` and use `COUNT`:

```
SELECT datum, COUNT(*) AS `Num. of visits`
FROM your_table
GROUP BY datum
ORDER BY datum
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was stucked on it for a long time.